# hide the whole column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

hide the column which it is in. I have created.

My table is below;

```
<table id="tester" border='1'>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>test1</td>
        <td>test2</td>
        <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>test1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>test1</td>
        <td>test2</td>
        <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>test1</td>
        <td>test2</td>
        <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>test1</td>
        <td>test2</td>
        <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

And the Jquery I am trying to get working is below;

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Iterate the td s and fetch their text with $('td').text() into a var and after it check thats var length. > 0

Comment: maybe a $('td:nth-child(2)').style.display="none"; works (i dont know)

Comment: it seems like the jsfiddle sample had the "pure js" as selection and as soon as I added jquery, it did hide a column. Is there more to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that youre looking for.

```
$.each($('table > tbody > tr'), function(){
  if($(this).find('td:empty').length>0){
    // You can hide
    $(this).hide();

    // Or Remove
    $(this).remove();

    // Or Fadeout and remove
    $(this).fadeOut(250, function(){$(this).remove();});
  }
});
```

Comment: Sorry I missunderstood your question. You need to include jQuery inside yxour jsfiddle and use the code I placed into my answear

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function hidecol2() {
    var cell = $('#tester > tbody > tr:eq(1) > td:eq(1)');
    if (cell.text() == '') cell.parent().parent().children().children(':nth-child(2)').hide;
};
```

Comment: Actually, `if (cell.is(':empty') == '')` is probably considered better style.

Comment: Sorry - my fault. Try this: `if (cell.text() == '') cell.parent().parent().children().children(':nth-child(2)').hide;`

Answer (score 0):

To hide the whole column if one of its cells is empty, use this:

```
$.each($('td:empty'), function(){
  $('td:nth-child(' + ($(this).index() + 1) + ')').hide();
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ScRn/2/)